# Uncaught TypeError: $.scrollTo is not a function

Tags: jquery

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   $.scrollTo($('#dle-content1'), 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: $("#dle-content1").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#dle-content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">Click</div>
<div id="dle-content1">123</div>
```

Comment: А можно сделать, чтоб скрипт всегда срабатывал при нажатии кнопки?

Comment: @Never3D, не совсем понял вопроса, разве она у Вас щас не всегда срабатывает?